# mod_rewrite change to subdirectory

Tags: mod-rewrite

hello I have this structure

```
http://localhost/ci2
```

with this .htaccess inside ci2

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^$ /ci2/index.php [L] 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resource|files|system|user_guide|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci2/index.php/$1 [L]
```

now I want to move the files to a subdirectory

```
http://localhost/folder/ci2
```

I realized that is not working with the same .htaccess file 
so what modifications are necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You should just need to change to:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resource|files|system|user_guide|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^folder/ci2/(.*)$ folder/ci2/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Sorted now and tested on my server.